# Is the sequence of time adverbials, place adverbials and manner adverbials appearing in the same sentence universal or typologically determined?

Tags: syntax, universal-grammar

For example, in English there is "I bought a dress with my friend at the mall yesterday" where the sequence is manner-place-time, while in Russian it is time-place-manner, in Mandarin it is time-manner-place, though the sequence is usually adjustable. I am not totally sure about the most usual sequence in the three languages, but there are indeed differences.

To what extent is the sequence universal and determined by cognitive factors? To what extent is the sequence language-specific? What are some researches about the topic?

Comment: Do you have a citation for the alleged order in Russian. Especially when considering shifting the focus of the sentence to different words.

Comment: @Vladimir F  page 529 in Wade, T., &amp; Gillespie, D. (2011). A comprehensive Russian grammar. Chichester: Wiley-Blackwell.

Comment: Thank you, Russian must be more strict than some other Slavic languages. I do not really speak it.